# Usar datos de la instancia Vue en template de Vue Router

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Cómo utilizar datos de la instancia Vue en los templates de las rutas de Vue Router.

Este es mi código

HTML

```
 <div id="app">
        <router-link to="/foo/1">ruta 1</router-link>
        <router-link to="/foo/2">ruta 2</router-link>

        <router-view></router-view>        
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);

    const Ruta1 = { template: '<div>{{ $route.params.numruta }}</div>' };
    const Ruta2 = { template: '<div>{{ $route.params.id }}</div>' };
    const router = new VueRouter({
        routes: [
            { path: '/foo/:numruta', component: Ruta1 },
            { path: '/foo/:numruta', component: Ruta2 }
        ]
    });
    const app = new Vue({
        router,
        el: "#app",
        data:{ 
            usuario:"nombre de usuario"
        }
    }).$mount('#app');
```

En ese caso utilizar el elemento `usuario` en el `templpate` de `Ruta1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tal y como está, podría facilitarte el trabajo accediendo a la instancia desde el componente, con `this.$root` , a partir de aquí, tienes acceso a tus métodos y data declarados en tu instancia.

**Ejm**

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const Ruta1 = { template: '<div>{{this.$root.usuario }}</div>' };
const Ruta2 = { template: '<div>Hola {{this.$root.op }}</div>' };
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/foo/:numruta', component: Ruta1 },
        { path: '/fooo/:numruta', component: Ruta2 }
    ]
});
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    el: "#app",
    data:{ 
        usuario:"Dev. Joel",
        op:"Emiliano",
    }
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <router-link to="/foo/1">Usuario</router-link>
    <router-link to="/fooo/2">OP</router-link>

    <router-view></router-view>        
</div>
```

Aunque también podría utilizar las `props` de las rutas definidas para pasar valores directamente.

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const Ruta1 = { props: ['usuario'] , template: '<div>Hola {{ usuario }}</div>' };
const Ruta2 = { props: ['usuario'] , template: '<div>Hola  {{ usuario }}</div>' };

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/uno', component: Ruta1 , props: { usuario: 'StackOverFlowEs' }},
        { path: '/dos', component: Ruta2 , props: { usuario: 'StackOverFlowEn' } }
    ]
});
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    el: "#app"
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <router-link to="/uno">Ruta 1</router-link>
    <router-link to="/dos">Ruta 2</router-link>

    <router-view></router-view>        
</div>
```

Comment: `props` es más especificamente para este caso ¿cierto? mientras que usar `this.$root`  puede ser utilizado en todos los "dominios" de Vue, cómo puede ser un `Vue.component` ¿es así?

Comment: Si, props es más especifico. Igual están las dos formas posibles. Saludos